# Shaman spontaneous casting

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, shaman

The Spirit Magic entry for the [Shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman) says:

> A shaman can spontaneously cast a limited number of spells per day
>   beyond those she prepared ahead of time. She has one spell slot per
>   day of each shaman spell level she can cast, not including orisons.
>   She can choose these spells from the list of spells granted by her
>   spirits (see the spirit class feature and the wandering spirit class
>   feature) at the time she casts them. She can enhance these spells
>   using any metamagic feat that she knows, using up a higher-level spell
>   slot as required by the feat and increasing the time to cast the spell
>   (see Spontaneous Casting and Metamagic Feats).

If I understand correctly, a Shaman can spontaneously cast only once a day for each spell level, and only from one of her spirit spells?

So a Level 3 Shaman with the Spirit of Battle has one level 1 slot that she can use to "spontaneously" cast Enlarge Person only, and one level 2 slot that she can use to "spontaneously" cast Fog Cloud only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lower-leveled spells can be cast from the same list**

Essentially, the Shaman gains 1 spell slot per level that can be used to cast *any* spell of that level or lower found on their spirit lists.

A hypothetical Level 3 Shaman could use their 1st-level Spirit Magic spell slot to cast the 1st-level spell granted by their Spirit, and then use the second level spell slot to cast the 1st-level spell *or* the 2nd-level spell granted by their Spirit.

At 4th level and beyond the Shaman can access the list of one other Spirit, doubling the number of spells to select from when spontaneously casting.

Comment: Ok, that's what I understood, but it felt so... limited that I thought maybe I was misunderstanding something

Comment: Yeah, the phrasing is odd. Why didn't they just word it similarly to Cleric domain spells?